# Blazor and DataTables: pass params like columns

Tags: datatables, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have integrated in my `Blazor WebAssembly` a `DataTables`. In the `index.html` I added the following javascript code

```
<script>
    function DataTablesAdd(table) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(table).DataTable();
        });
    }

    function DataTablesRemove(table) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(table).DataTable().destroy();
            // Removes the datatable wrapper from the dom.
            var elem = document.querySelector(table + '_wrapper');
            elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
        });
    }
</script>
```

In a Razor page I added

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
@implements IDisposable

@code {
    public void Dispose()
    {
        JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<bool>("DataTablesRemove", "#tableData");
    }

    protected async override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("DataTablesAdd", new string[] { "#tableData" });
        await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
    }
}
```

The `DataTables` is working. Now, I want to not order some columns, for example in the following image I don't want to order by *Gap analysis* and *Publication Plan*.

[image]

So, in the `index.html` I added another function

```
function DataTablesAdd(table, columns) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(table).DataTable({
            "columns": columns
        });
    });
}
```

In the page I added this C# code

```
protected async override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    string cols = "[{ name = \"Username\", orderable = \"true\" }, " +
                  "{ name = \"Gap analysis\", orderable = \"false\" }," +
                  "{ name = \"Publication plan\", orderable = \"false\" }," +
                  "{ name = \"Last update\", orderable = \"true\" }]";

    await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("DataTablesAdd", new string[] { "#tableData" }, cols);
    await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work and also the DataTables is not applied to the table for a `jQuery` error.

How can I pass same parameters to the javascript function and use them in the `DataTables` definition?

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the arguments to the JavaScript function as object array.

```
protected async override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
  string cols = "[{ name = \"Username\", orderable = \"true\" }, " +
              "{ name = \"Gap analysis\", orderable = \"false\" }," +
              "{ name = \"Publication plan\", orderable = \"false\" }," +
              "{ name = \"Last update\", orderable = \"true\" }]";

  await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("DataTablesAdd", new object[] { "#tableData", cols });
  await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
}
```

At the JavaScript capture the columns string and parse it back to JavaScript object as follows.

```
function DataTablesAdd(table, columns) {
   $(document).ready(function () {
     $(table).DataTable({
        "columns": JSON.parse(columns)
     });
   });
}
```

*Disclaimer: I have not tested the code.*

Comment: Thank you for your comment but it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

For now, I found a very simple way to resolve this issue. I changed the function for adding a `DataTables` like the following code

```
function DataTablesAdd(table) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(table).DataTable({
            "order": [],
            "columnDefs": [{
                "targets": 'no-sort',
                "orderable": false,
            }]
        });
    });
}
```

Then, where I define the table, I add the `class` with value `no-sort`.

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="tableData">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Last update</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th class="no-sort">Gap analysis</th>
            <th class="no-sort">Publication plan</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
</table>
```

So, the DataTables render doesn't allow to sort for the headers with `class="no-sort"`.

I still have to sort out how to pass data from the function parameters to DataTables.